# Cannot get transparent Tab Bar in tvOS

Tags: swift, uitabbar, tvos

I'm having a hard time getting a UITabBar with a completely transparent background on tvOS : I Always get a whitish background.
I tried the following (Setting background color clear, background image to UIImage) but nothing worked.

```
var appearanceTabBar = UITabBar.appearance()
    appearanceTabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
    appearanceTabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    appearanceTabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Result is the following :

[image]

does anybody have any idea on how i can make the background completely transparent ?
Setting the color as the same purple is not a good idea as a picture may be on the background.

Thank you :)

Mickael

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue, you have to wait for the tab bar UI to be "ready". I solved it inheriting from UITabBarController and overriding `viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
}
```

I guess you don't have to extend from UITabBarController, you probably can achieve the same result just overriding `viewWillAppear` on your main view controller.